# How to change the number of the buttons in Ckeditor in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ckeditor

I have installed the ckeditor gem, it works fine. When I try to use :toolbar => "mini" I get the same number of items in the toolbar as the full. Shouldn't I get less buttons in the toolbar?

This is my code in one of the edit viwes:

```
<%= f.input :content, :as => :ckeditor, :input_html => { :ckeditor => {:toolbar => 'mini'} } %>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer: [Answer](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor/issues/379)

You need define this toolbar in ckeditor/config.js:

```
config.toolbar_mini = [
  { name: 'links', items: [ 'Link', 'Unlink', 'Anchor' ] }
];
```

Cheers